# Android seebar - how does the ValueAnimator determine the animation speed?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, seekbar

**CONTEXT:**
I want to make my vertical `SeekBar`'s value progression to be a "piece wise linear function". In other words, my value progression looks like this:

[image]
"db" stands for decibel. As you can see in the beautiful graphic above, my `SeekBar` is split into segments (s1, s2, s3), which in turn consist of linear functions. In practice, the bottom 1/10 of the `SeekBar` (s1) accounts for 3/10 of the max value in db.

Currently, I have a `fun` that serves as an adapter, translating the linear progress value of the `SeekBar` into a db number. I read the progress value of the `SeekBar`, determine the segment, then multiply it with the linear function for the segment. I was wondering if it would be possible to remove the adapter and instead implement it directly as part of the `SeekBar`.

**GOAL:**
I extend the `SeekBar` class and override its `fun getProgress` to have it return the progress value adjusted with the function above, instead of its regular, linear progress value. Now, I want to animate the `SeekBar` to have its value fall from max value to min value at a rate of 20db/1.7s. This means A) The higher the value, the longer the animation and B) the non-linear function should affect the animation speed among the different segments.

**QUESTION:**
Does the `ValueAnimator` reference the `fun getProgress` in order to determine the animation speed or does it use the graphical distance between start value and goal value?

**NOTE:**
When I animate the `SeekBar` to go from max to min, I want it to first go very fast, then slower and finally, even slower. If it only takes the graphical distance from max to min in account, it will disregard the function I sketched above and go from top to bottom at a constant speed.

Comment: ValueAnimator uses an [Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator) that mutates input (real progress) to output (interpolated progress). By default its linear but you can change it to one of the presets like AccelerateInterpolator, DecelerateInterpolator or write your own.